# Access a directives scope variable from another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with a function and I access that function at the click of a button. What I want to do is to access a `$scope` variable from that function into another directive and use it in that directive's view

Here is the code for the directive that has the function defined in it:

```
$scope.footerLinkClicked = function (item2) {
    $scope.myvalue = true;  
    console.log("parameter received :" );

    $scope.item1 = item2;
    console.log($scope.item1);

    $rootScope.$broadcast('item1',$scope.item1);
}
```

In my other directive's view I want to do something like

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-show="myvalue">
```

Now, what I want is to acces myvalue variable in another directive. What is the way to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a directive's scope variable from another directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140817/accessing-a-directives-scope-variable-from-another-directive)

Comment: You can do this by using a parent controller assigned variable or a service.

Comment: something like broadcasting myvalue to a parent controller and then accessing it from there ?

Answer (score 0):

Its better two use object instead of primitive variable.

```
<one-d  my-value="objVal"></one-d>


<two-d  my-value="objVal"></two-d>
```

In the directive script you should use  like this

```
    return {
    scope: { myValue: '=' },
    link: function(scope, ele, attr) {

        scope.footerLinkClicked = function(item2) {
            scope.myValue.data = true;
            scope.item1 = item2;

        }

      }
  }
```